# Counterexample to a recursive matched parenthesis proposition.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, computer-science, examples-counterexamples, computability

I am attempting problem 7.28 of Discrete Mathematics notes from MIT OCW. **[Link to problem](http://opendatastructures.org/mcs.pdf#page=257)**

---

**Definitions:**  All recursively defined

- RecMatch (RM):

  - Base Case: $\lambda \in RM$ [$\lambda$ is empty string]
  - Constructor Case: $s,t \in RM \implies \color{red}[s\color{blue}]t \in RM$
  - Eg.: $\color{red}[\lambda\color{blue}]\lambda = \color{red}[\color{blue}] \in RM \ and \ \color{red}{[[}\color{blue}{]]}\color{red}[\color{blue}] \in RM$
- Arithmetic Expression (AE):

  - Base Case:

    - (a.) $x \in AE$ where $x$ is the only variable allowed
    - (b.) $k \in AE$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$
  - Constructor Case: Let $a,b \in AE$; then

    - $\color{red}[a + b\color{blue}] \in AE$
    - $\color{red}[a * b\color{blue}] \in AE$
    - $-\color{red}[a\color{blue}] \in AE$
  - Eg.:

    - $3x^2 + 2x + 1 = \color{red}{[[}3 * \color{red}[x * x\color{blue}{]]}+\color{red}{[[}2*x\color{blue}]+1\color{blue}{]]} \in AE$
    - $x(x-1) = \color{red}[x * \color{red}[x +-\color{red} [1\color{blue}{]]]}\in AE$
- erase($e$): erases the symbols in $e$ where $e \in AE$.
  So erase($\color{red}{[[}3 * \color{red}[x * x\color{blue}{]]}+\color{red}{[[}2*x\color{blue}]+1\color{blue}{]]}$ = $\color{red}{[[[}\color{blue}{]]}\color{red}{[[}\color{blue}{]]]}$)

---

**Problem:** Give an example of a small string $s \in RM$ such that $\color{red}[s\color{blue}] \neq erase(e)\ \text{for any}\ e\in AE$

I have tried many strings $s \in RM$ like $\lambda, \color{red}{[}\color{blue}], \color{red}{[[}\color{blue}{]]}\ \text{and}\ \color{red}[\color{blue}]\color{red}[\color{blue}]$ but for all these I can come up with an $e \in AE$ so that $\color{red}[s\color{blue}] = erase(e).$

Could anyone give me a hint so that I could solve this?

Comment: How do you get $\color{red}[\color{blue}]\color{red}[\color{blue}]$?  That looks like the required example to me.  In all the constructions for AE, the first left bracket matches the last right bracket.

Comment: @saulspatz If $s = \color{red}[\color{blue}]\color{red}[\color{blue}]$ then $\color{red}[s\color{blue}]$ = erase($\color{red}{[[}2*x\color{blue}] + -\color{red}[ 3\color{blue}{]]}$)

Comment: Did you try $[][][]$?

Comment: @MitchellSpector Yeah I finally figured it out a couple hours ago. I went down the wrong recursive path while building strings, but now it seems obvious. I am now tring to write a proof about why this case doesn't work; once I'm done with that I'll answer thequestion. Still, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Yes, I misunderstood the question.  I  was thinking $s\neq erase(e)$ rather than $[s]\neq erase(e)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the question and now posting my solution.

$s = \color{red}[\color{blue}]\color{red}[\color{blue}]\color{red}[\color{blue}] \in RM\ \text{such that}\ \color{red}[s\color{blue}] \neq erase(e)\ \text{for any}\ e \in AE$ since only two arithmetic expressions can be used to make a new arithmetic expressions. For three matched brackets to occur simultaneously, three AEs must be used to then form a single AE which is not allowed.